# Problems with network adapter within VM Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware

I'm having trouble with my virtualized machine connecting to my network. Here is what I'm running:

Host: 12.04.3 LTS Unity (connects to internet just fine.
VM Virtual Box v 4.1.12
Guest: XUbuntu 12.04

Everything was running correctly yesterday (and has been for the past month and a half). Last night, I left everything running. This morning, I woke up and the network had disconnected and was just cycling trying to connect. Steps I took to resolve:

1. Tried to boot one of the clones of that machine- Same issue
2. Deleted the clones, cloned the main image again, booted clone, same issue
3. Updated host- same issue
4. Updated VM Virtualbox - Same issue
5. Updated one of the clones to 13.10- same issue
6. Removed and reinstalled Virtualbox- same issue
7. Changed the mode for the network on the guest from NAT to bridged (and set adapter to eth) - same issue
8. Changed the adapter in the guest- same issue
9. Installed a new VBox with 13.10 for fun and testing- works

The virtual box boots and I believe it initially connects to a network successfully. It logs into Teamviewer and sync drop box and comes up and tells me I have updates to install. The it starts cycling. While it is cycling, sometimes it will stay stable for a moment and allow me to get to google or something. Then it just sits and cycles over and over.

I did not change any settings recently other my VPN provider between then and now. And I figured that shouldn't have an effect since I connect to the VPN on that Vmachine manually. But it was on last night connected to that VPN. I just don't understand what would have caused this. I thank you for your time and feedback. Would love to get this solved ASAP. I'm open to suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Bueller....Bueller?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/l/sdTXEmV9kmSfGn3GoQjuKb

Answer (score 1):

Solved: Long ago I created a script that ran at startup. It started the VPN. It seemed broken. But after changing the vpn, it cause the issue. Deleted it and BOOM.